# gpgtar вместо gpg-zip. Как использовать полный путь в аргументе gpgtar?

Tags: bash, gpg

Недавно при архивации gpg-zip стал получать сообщение:

```
gpg-zip: This script is deprecated - please use gpgtar instead.
```

Ранее я архивировал  bash скриптом такой командой:

```
cd $output_dir
gpg-zip -e -r $key "$input_dir" | split -b 1000m
```

Причем $input_dir была полным путем к архивируемой директории.
Проблема в том, что при архивации gpgtar вместо полного пути требуется только имя директории. А значит прежде я должен переместится на каталог выше $input_dir, затем начать архивирование, а потом перемещать архив в $output_dir.
Но и этот "костыльный" вариант не подходит, поскольку объем создаваемого архива большой и объема диска на котором находится директория $input_dir может не хватить.
Я бы не думал об этом, но поскольку gpg-zip объявлен устаревшим, то возможно вскоре будет исключен из пакета. 
Как мне решить эту проблему?

Comment: п.с. добавить опцию "-o $output_dir/file" тоже не очень удобна поскольку не выполняется "split -b 1000m"

Comment: Я думаю там команды должны быть похожи на `tar`, то есть что-то типа `tar -C "$input_dir" -c ...`

Comment: `$ tar -c ... | gpg -e -r ... | ...`

Comment: tar -czpf - .... | gpg -e -r ... | split -b ... работает

Comment: `-f -` — излишне. программа *tar* и так по умолчанию записывает в *stdout*. явно это указывать с помощью `-f -` не нужно.